# How to convert date/time in multilingual Cakephp 3 website

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, multilingual

I have a multilingual website in both English and Danish.

Everything works fine, but when I am on the Danish version the date/time is incorrect.

Can you please help me how can I get correct date/time in Danish the translation.

```
[birth_time] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
    (
        [time] => 2017-06-27T11:20:00+00:00
        [timezone] => UTC
        [fixedNowTime] => 
    )
```

Comment: Please clarify and expand on what you're tried, what specifically you're expecting vs what is happening...etc.

Comment: Could you share the code you have where the problem arises? It's not clear from your current question what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Danish? Well I think that is Denmark, in bootstrap in config, maybe you should config:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
```

or time zone that you using should be:

```
[birth_time] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
        (
            [time] => 2017-06-27T11:20:00+00:00
            [timezone] => UTC+01:00
            [fixedNowTime] => 
        )
```

now for set or get should [create instances](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#creating-time-instances):

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;

// Create from a string datetime.
$time = Time::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    $datetime,
    'Europe/Copenhagen'
)
```